# My Bootstrap columns aren't lining up

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I used to have a working layout of a header, side navigation column, main large content column , and a footer. Now the navigation column is sitting on top of the content column even though the numbers should add up. I just need my navigation column to line up next to my content. You can see my [WIP HERE](http://www.jessejaymesjones.com/NEW_VERSION/index_v04.html). What am I doing wrong?

Here is basically what my code for my layout is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">
            <p>HEADER</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <p>NAVIGATION</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-footer">
            <p>FOOTER</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: WORKS! Although I had to remove the offset classes from the content div. Thank you so much for the help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column divs only line up beside each  other for the divs actually are "siblings" to each other, apart from adding up numberwise.

Try putting the navigation and content columns in the same container -> row tag, like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <p>NAVIGATION</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0">
            <p>CONTENT</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, as you pointed out in the comments to your question, there is also an offset class which disturbs the layout a bit as well. Didn't notice it at first.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your code, it looks like you want your columns next to each other. This should work

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-header">
        <p>HEADER</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <p>NAVIGATION</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 col-xs-offset-0">
        <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="page-footer">
        <p>FOOTER</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately this is not working. Now the columns are on top of each other and staggered. You can see this [HERE](http://www.http://jessejaymesjones.com/NEW_VERSION/index_v05.html) Any suggestions? I appreciate it! :)